# Dynamic Order By Clause including Calculated Column Doesn't Work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a statement like this:

```
DECLARE @OrderBy nvarchar(50)
SELECT
    t1.Forename,
    t1.Surname,
/** Calculcated Column Start **/
    (
    SELECT
      (
      SELECT Count(FulfilledDelivery) FROM dbo.Deliveries d1 WHERE d1.UserID = t1.UserID
      )
      -
      (
      SELECT Count(CancelledDelivery) FROM dbo.Deliveries d1 WHERE d1.UserID = t1.UserID
      )
    ) AS 'Deliveries'
/** Calculcated Column End **/

FROM
    TableName t1
WHERE
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Deliveries' THEN 'Deliveries' END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Forename' THEN t1.Forename END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Surname' THEN t1.Surname END DESC
    END;
```

Basically, this works fine except the calculated column '`Deliveries`' does not work in the OrderBy clause. I don't get any errors from my SQL code but it simply doesn't order by the calculcated column 'Deliveries' when I set the @OrderBy parameter to "Deliveries".

If I remove the dynamic order by clause, then it works fine like this:

```
.... 
ORDER BY 
   'Deliveries' DESC;
```

How can I make it work in the dynamic version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes alias name can't be accessed in the order by , you can use CTE and get the name for the calculated column or you need to repeat whole calculation in order by also

```
;WITH CTE T
as
(
SELECT
    t1.Forename,
    t1.Surname,
/** Calculcated Column Start **/
    (
    SELECT
      (
      SELECT Count(FulfilledDelivery) FROM dbo.Deliveries d1 WHERE d1.UserID = t1.UserID
      )
      -
      (
      SELECT Count(CancelledDelivery) FROM dbo.Deliveries d1 WHERE d1.UserID = t1.UserID
      )
    ) AS 'Deliveries'
/** Calculcated Column End **/

FROM
    TableName t1
)
SELECT * FROM T
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Deliveries' THEN T.Deliveries END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Forename' THEN T.Forename END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Surname' THEN T.Surname END DESC
    END;
```

Comment: Is this an efficient way to do it? I ask because hundreds of users will be sorting their results at the same time.

Comment: @volume one, yes this should be scalable, another approach is put calculated result value and id in a temp table an join with temp table and use temp table column in order by